Where is the program counter stored in the AVR architecture
I'm writing an emulator for the ATMEGA328P, and after looking through the datasheet I could not find the specific address at which the PC is located, a ton of information is mentioned on other registers, SP, SREG etc, the PC itself is talked about but never said where in memory it lays .
I have checked this out from microchip, but since I'm emulating the whole processor it doesn't obviusly work for me.
https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/How-to-access-the-Program-Counter-in-AVR
So where in memory is the PC?, also the behaviour of it is kind of hidden, to which address does it point after a RESET for example

It looks like it's not stored in memory. That's why you can't access it, as the page you linked to says.

As the linked article says - PC isn't directly accessible. In your emulator it might be located in some memory, which is accessible from the host not from the emulated system. Not sure why you can't read the value using that sequence from the article though. Unless the emulator is only partial.

to which address does it point after a RESET for example - in this article it says that AVR have reset vector at address zero.

@EugeneSh. I'm currently writing the emulator, so it is indeed partial, in the end I have chosen to create a new phanthom register, actually two, PCH PCL to store the address and call it a day, but was curious about what was there to say

I see. Sure, you need to keep track of your PC somehow. It is there somewhere, it just does not have "public interface". In the hardware it is still a register, but in your emulator it will be just some internal variable I guess. Or not exactly  internal, you might want to opt displaying it somehow for debugging purposes.

The AVR architecture is special in having its CPU registers and SFRs in addressable memory. Looking at the history of CPUs and MCUs, this is only one way. Many other architectures separate registers and IO (say: SFR) from memory and provide no way to access them other than by dedicated instructions.

If you are writing an emulator, the bare minimum of effort required would be to read the CPU manual regarding the core and assembly language used. For low-end old parts like this, such manuals are actually relatively straight-forward to read.


So where in memory is the PC?

Nowhere.  The PC has no associated memory address, neither an I/O address.  In a simulator, you would just add a variable or property that holds the PC.
When an application needs the PC, it can perform something like rcall . and then read the 2-byte resp. 3-byte word-address from the stack.  A use case would be a program that is relocateable, though I don't know whether there are compilers out there that support it (the GNU tools don't), and even application that would require such a thing.

to which address does it [PC] point after a RESET

The reset vector is the first entry in the interrupt vector table (IVT).  There are AVR devices where the location depends on fuses.  For the purpose of simulation, the program could start at the value of the entry symbol as provided by ELF, so that the user can specify where the code should start.  The default entry point of code generated by the GNU tools is address 0x0.
As a final remark, when you see rcall . in a compiler-generated code, then it is used to allocate some bytes in the frame of a function like:
void func (int*);

void caller (void)
{
  int x;
  func (&x);
}

That avr-gcc compiles to:
caller:
    push r28
    push r29
     ; SP -= 2   ;  20  [c=4 l=1]  *addhi3_sp
    rcall . 
    in r28,__SP_L__
    in r29,__SP_H__
/* prologue: function */
/* frame size = 2 */
/* stack size = 4 */
    movw r24,r28
    adiw r24,1
    rcall func
/* epilogue start */
     ; SP += 2   ;  26  [c=4 l=2]  *addhi3_sp
    pop __tmp_reg__
    pop __tmp_reg__
    pop r29
    pop r28
    ret

